# Difference between std and t distributions

Tags: r, distribution

I have a question regarding the definitions std and t of the student-t distribution in R. std comes with the **rugarch** package, while t is from the stats package. When plotting

```
qqplot(qstd(c(1:1000)/1001, nu=5),qt(c(1:1000)/1001,df=5)) 
abline(0,1)
```

it is clear to see that the two definitions are different. Can anyone tell me why there is this difference and which one of the functions gives the correct values?

Comment: Isn't it simply a sampling problem? If you increase your sample to, say, a million points how does that look?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately it is not a sampling problem, the qstd and qt functions are simply returning different quantile values for the t distribution.

Comment: `qstd` is a function of the package `fGarch`. I don't now yet the meaning, but `qstd(c(1:1000)/1001, nu=5),qt(c(1:1000)/1001,df=5)` is a constant.

Answer (score 1):

If you open up the `qstd` function (which is actually from **fGarch**), you'll see that it's modifying `stats::qt`:

```
> qstd
function (p, mean = 0, sd = 1, nu = 5) 
{
    s = sqrt(nu/(nu - 2))
    result = qt(p = p, df = nu) * sd/s + mean
    result
}
<environment: namespace:fGarch>
```

So, what it's giving you is a ["non-standardized Student's t-distribution"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Non-standardized_Student.27s_t-distribution) as opposed to the standardized distribution available from **stats**. If `s=1` and as degrees of freedom goes to infinity, they will produce the same result.

Comment: Now I know why there is a constant.

Comment: @Rosenlund If you found the answer helpful, please remember to Up vote it and mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.